# Is there anything preventing C++ from optimizing global variables?

Tags: c++, winapi

As far as I know, C++ knows nothing about threads (before C++11 standard I guess).

So say I have the following pseudo-code:

```
int i = 0;

function foo()
{
    i++;
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main()
{

    CreateThread(...,foo,...);
    foo();

    Sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Since a C++ compiler knows nothing about threads, it will only see that one thread is modifying `i`, so the compiler could just store the value of `i` in a register. And now when the program runs, each of the two threads will have a register that represents `i` with the value of `0`, and each thread will increment its own register to `1`!

Am I correct in my assumption? and is there a way to tell a C++ compiler not to optimize global variables (I am using Visual C++ 2010).

Comment: Just compile it in C++11 compiler...

Comment: You must use synchronization to protect access to `i` from multiple threads. C++11 added this feature to the language; prior to C++11 you had to use operating system features such as Critical Sections

Comment: @M.M But a compiler doesn't know anything about critical sections (as far as the compiler is concerned, `EnterCriticalSection()` and `LeaveCriticalSection()` are just regular functions), so by the time the C++ code is compiled into machine code, the global variable is gone, and the instructions inside the critical section only work on the register.

Comment: Use `volatile` keywork.

Comment: @Zefick, in the *particular* case of Visual Studio 2010, and sometimes in later versions of Visual Studio depending on the value of the `/volatile` compiler option, the `volatile` keyword provides memory ordering semantics.  It doesn't provide atomic semantics, so `i++` might still not work as expected, though in practice I believe it will on x86 and amd64 processors.

Comment: @Christopher, any call to an external function will stop Visual Studio 2010 from optimizing the global variable out of existence.  It might still use a register the rest of the time, but if so, the value in the register will always be written to memory before the external call and read back from it afterwards.

Comment: (As per the rather confused discussion on your earlier question, some third-party compilers might do more aggressive optimization in some cases, but shouldn't do so in this particular case.)

Comment: Incidentally, the `InterlockedIncrement` function is a *much* more efficient way of atomically incrementing a variable than using a critical section.

Comment: The global variable has *external linkage* so it can't be optimized away. The compiler has no idea what other binary objects will access it at link time.

Comment: @Christopher functions might modify global variables

Comment: @Galik: Visual Studio 2010 already had Link Time Code Generation (/LTCG)

Comment: @Harry Johnston *"any call to an external function will stop Visual Studio 2010 from optimizing the global variable out of existence"* Is this because the compiler doesn't know if the function accesses the global variable, and so the global variable must remain existent just in case the function access it?

Comment: What are you trying to get in a correctly behaving program? Your current program is UB.

Comment: @Christopher - yes, only if function not special marked with [`__declspec(noalias)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k649tyc7(v=vs.100).aspx). and your example have no sense at all. you not care about any synchronization here. if  write `cout << _InterlockedIncrement((long*)&i)) << endl;` all will be 100% correct worked.

Comment: @Christopher, exactly.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is **undefined behavior**.

Just like bank transaction, accessing a variable simultaneously is not allowed.

Choose one:

1. `std::atomic` (C++11) or compiler specific intrinsics.
2. `std::mutex` (C++11) or its Windows equavilent.